# Passing event to callback function

Tags: javascript, this

I am using the summernote api (http://summernote.org/#/deep-dive), and using the callback for onkeyup as follows:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
    height: 150,
    onkeyup: myFunction
});
```

for the html:

```
<textarea id="summernote"></textarea>
```

I defined myFunction as ...

```
var myFunction= function(e) {
    var num_chars = $(e.target).text().length
    console.log(num_chars);
}
```

Now I would like to pass some parameters with .bind() to myFunction.
When I do

```
onkeyup: myFuntion.bind(1,2)
```

$(this) or e.target does not work, this probably has to do with how params are shuffled around when use the .bind()

How do I maintain e.target functionality and pass extra data to the function with bind?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might find this eventHandler documentation helpful. [API docs](http://summernote.org/jsduck/#!/api/EventHandler) Seems you might be able to access all sorts of event objects with `$.summernote.eventHandler.methodOfYourChoice();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `bind` in this manner. You're trying to partially apply arguments from the right side of the function (because you want the first argument to be the event). In addition, `bind(1, 2)` sets `this` to `1` and passes `2` to the invoked function. It *looks* like you want something like this:

```
onkeyup: _.partialRight(myFunction, 1, 2);

function myFunction(event, data1, data2) {
  var numChars = $(e.target).text().length;
  console.log(numChars);
}
```

However, you MIGHT lose the `this` binding. If you want to preserve that you should use `bind` again, but like this:

```
onkeyup: _.partialRight(myFunction.bind($), 1, 2); // This will bind this to $

function myFunction(event, data1, data2) {
  var numChars = this(e.target).text().length; // because this is $
}
```

`_` in this example is lodash.

The reason you do this (and that you can't use bind for it) is because bind partially applies from the *left*. This means that it will pass it your arguments *first*, and then any arguments passed to the bound function when it is invoked will be passed afterwards. In other words, with your original set up, you get this:

```
myFunction(2, event); // "this" is 1
```

Rather than what you want, which is:

```
myFunction(event, 1, 2); // "this" is undefined behaviour
```

To do this you just need to partially apply the function above, which will give you the desired behaviour. The reason we use `partialRight` is because this causes all the arguments passed to the invoked function to be applied first and then the arguments passed to bind. If you did not use `partialRight` and instead used `partial`, you would instead get this:

```
myFunction(1, 2, event); // "this" is undefined behaviour
```

*This bit might be a bit beyond your reach*

`bind` sets the ThisBinding of a function to the `this` provided. Any extra arguments passed are partially applied (from the left) to the function, and then the resultant function is returned. This means that the next time you invoke the resultant function, it will invoke the function with the ThisBinding that you supplied in bind, plus the arguments you supplied in bind, plus any EXTRA arguments you passed as welll

Comment: Disclaimer: I've never used summernote before so there might be an easier way of doing this; I'm just giving a plain ol JS approach

Comment: I fear I didn't explain it very well as I don't fully understand exactly *how* partial application works myself, only what it actually does. So forgive me any die-hard FPers

Comment: No that was a really good read! I apologize for the late reply. I will definitely try this out. Had no idea JavaScript could do such things!

Answer (score 1):

The further I review the API documents, I think the answer might be located within the provided `eventHandler()` method.

Here you have access to `bindKeyMap(layoutInfo, keyMap)` where `keyMap` is an object.

Perhaps something like: `$.summernote.eventHandler.bindKeyMap();` will give what you need?

[Documents for bindKeyMap()](http://summernote.org/jsduck/source/EventHandler.html#EventHandler-method-bindKeyMap)

[Documents for eventHandler()](http://summernote.org/jsduck/#!/api/EventHandler)